# Closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by the graph of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I want to show that the set

$$A := \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|y ≤ f(x)\}$$

induced by $f$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now intuitively, it seems kind of obvious that it's the case, but how can it be properly proven? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To show that it is closed, you need only to show that it contains all its limit  points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \in A$ such that $\lim x_n=x$ and $\lim y_n=y$, since $f$ is continuous we have $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$, so we have: $$ y=\lim y_n \leq \lim f(x_n)=f(x) $$ Hence $(x,y)\in A$ which means that $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

We could also set $g(x,y) = f(x)-y.$ This is a continuous function on $\mathbb {R}^2.$ Because $[0,\infty)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R},$ the set $g^{-1}([0,\infty))$ is closed in $\mathbb {R}^2.$ Now $g^{-1}([0,\infty)) =A,$ so we're done.